# Nested forEach: Uncaught TypeError: data.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript

I don't want to use any for loop or any of the regular loops, I am trying to use a `forEach` but I am getting an error

> Uncaught TypeError: data.forEach is not a function

```
return falsyData.map(function(data) {
  data.forEach(function(key) {
    if (key.match(reg)) {
      return key;
    }
  });
});
```

but if I do it this way it works:

```
return falsyData.map(function(data) {
  for (var key in data) {
    if (key.match(reg)) {
      return key;
    }
  }
});
```

why ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`data` is an object - `forEach` only runs on Array types. You have to use a `for..in` loop to iterate the keys of an object.

Comment: I will have to use `lodash` then.

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer -- Yeah, or `underscore.js`