# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data.forEach is not a function how can resol

Tags: javascript, json, es6-promise, fetch-api

I fetch JSON data from my local server. But when I fetch the data code giving me a error like

> data.forEach not a function

I know JSON data is an object, not an array, but how can I convert object to array in this code?

```
 function userfun() {
    fetch("user.json")
      .then(function (res) {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        // console.log(data);

        let output = "";
        data.forEach(function(user){
            output += `<ul>
            <li>Name ${user.name}</li>
            <li>Age ${user.age}</li>
            <li>Class ${user.class}</li>
            </ul>`
        });
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = output;
      });
  }
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379274/how-to-iterate-over-a-javascript-object). If you know your `data` is not an Array, but an Object, simply look up how to iterate an object.

Comment: That means data comes in `data` is not an array...It is an object

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nested forEach: Uncaught TypeError: data.forEach is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32359735/nested-foreach-uncaught-typeerror-data-foreach-is-not-a-function)